# OpenCV: Converting from NumPy to IplImage in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that I load using cv2.imread().  This returns an NumPy array.  However, I need to pass this into a 3rd party API that requires the data in IplImage format.

I've scoured everything I could and I've found instances of converting from IplImage to CvMat,and I've found some references to converting in C++, but not from NumPy to IplImage in Python.  Is there a function that is provided that can do this conversion?

Comment: Is it okay with Numpy --> cvMat?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
source = cv2.imread() # source is numpy array 
bitmap = cv.CreateImageHeader((source.shape[1], source.shape[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(bitmap, source.tostring(), 
           source.dtype.itemsize * 3 * source.shape[1])
```

`bitmap` here is `cv2.cv.iplimage`

Comment: Thanks Froyo, this gets me an IplImage, but the image seems to be corrupt.  Instead of using cv.CreateImageHeader and cv.SetData, I'm using cv2.cv.CreateImageHearder and cv2.cv.SetData, do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: Actually I figured it out, the tile I was trying to convert was binary, not BGR, so that's why it was getting corrupt.  So I changed 3 to 1 and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.  In case anyone else needs it, the OpenCV Cookbook has info on how to convert at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface/

Answer (score 0):

2-way to apply:

1. `img = cv2.imread(img_path)
   img_buf = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()`
2. just read the image file:
   `img_buf = open(img_path, 'rb').read()`