# Python OpenCV 3.0 and cv module

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

Since `cv` module has been removed from OpenCV 3.0, where can I find its functionality in newer versions?

Specifically I'm looking for `CreateImageHeader`, `IPL_DEPTH_8U`, `SetData`.

Comment: try a `help (cv2)` , to see, what's in the cv2 successor module. also: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html

Comment: I've searched through the module and submodules and coulnd't find nor `cv` in there neither `CreateImageHeader`

Comment: if you need them for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170752/python-opencv-load-image-from-byte-string/72290986#72290986 then you probably do not need them at all.