# CreateImageHeader in OpenCV 3.x

Tags: python, opencv

I am having trouble with this line of code.

```
cv_im = cv.CreateImageHeader(pil_im.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
```

Now, I am using OpenCV 3.x which apparently has no such attribute. Is there any substitute for that in version 3.x?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163597/python-opencv-3-0-and-cv-module.

Comment: @berak I don't know if it is outdated. Since I was looking at it anyway I just cleaned it up.