# How can i convert blob data received from database to image in python

Tags: python, blob, opencv

I receive longblob data from database.

and i try to convert blob data to image and read image using cv2.

So I tried converting blob data to base64 like below code but it failed.

```
img = base64.decodebytes(img_str)
```

How can i convert blob to image? Is there a converting feature for this problem in the cv2 package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need cv2 for convert blob to image, you need to store on disk the blob/image and show it. here and example of retrive from mysql blob to disk file..

Good luck!

Page URL referenced:[URL](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/)

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def write_file(data, filename):
    # Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)

def readBLOB(emp_id, photo, bioData):
    print("Reading BLOB data from python_employee table")

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='python_db',
                                             user='pynative',
                                             password='pynative@#29')

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT photo from python_employee where id = %s"""

        cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id,))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in record:
            print("Id = ", row[0], )
            print("Name = ", row[1])
            image = row[2]
            file = row[3]
            print("Storing employee image and bio-data on disk \n")
            write_file(image, photo)
            write_file(file, bioData)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

readBLOB(1, "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\query_output\eric_photo.png",
         "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\query_output\eric_bioData.txt")
readBLOB(2, "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\query_output\scott_photo.png",
         "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\query_output\scott_bioData.txt")
```

Comment: photo is the file (blob), and bioData is a text value, is only an example i have. you only need photo parameter

Comment: Is there a way to convert a data without saving it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170752/python-opencv-load-image-from-byte-string The answer in this question helped me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the image, use the code from 'Danilo Mercado Oudalova'.

But if you want to use without save file, use the example below.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from io import BytesIO #from io import StringIO.
import PIL.Image



try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='python_db',
                                         user='pynative',
                                         password='pynative@#29')

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "your query"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))

finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")

type(result[0][0])
#If the type is byte, use from io import BytesIOf. If str, use from io import StringIO.
file_like= BytesIO(result[0][0])
img=PIL.Image.open(file_like)
img.show()
```