# how to recognize an object using library?

Tags: opencv, tesseract

could you please help with my questions?

1.
how to detect multi objects?

2.
how to detect the object that I want?

Thank you!

Comment: imagine there's a vertical centerline dividing the picture into two parts (left and right). I just want the program to tell me what is the bottom-row letter that is penetrated by the centerline.

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting the image in 9 sections and cut the part you are 
interested in, write it to a file and then run tesseract on it.

```
tesseract myscan.png out
```

I don't know how/if tesseract can operate on images in memory... But may be you will find something in the API docs?

I think tesseract will return a text with 3 lines, you are interested in 
the word in the middle area of the last line. Is it helping? :D

Ok I have just played around with python tesseract api and python opencv api and came up with the following

```
import cv2    
import cv2.cv as cv    
import tesseract    

cv.NamedWindow("win")    
img = cv2.imread("GBIAe.jpg") # numpy.ndarray     
height, width, channels = img.shape    

# crop the image     
crop = (2*height/3, width/3)    
roi  = img[crop[0]:height, crop[1]:2*width/3]    

# Convert numpy.ndarray, to cv2.cv.iplimage
bitmap = cv.CreateImageHeader((roi.shape[1], roi.shape[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(bitmap, roi.tostring(), roi.dtype.itemsize * 3 * roi.shape[1] )    

# Extract the text with tesseract     
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()    
api.Init(".","eng", tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)    
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)    
tesseract.SetCvImage( bitmap, api)    
text=api.GetUTF8Text()    
conf=api.MeanTextConf()    
print("text %s" % text)    
api.End()    
cv.ShowImage("win", bitmap)    
cv.WaitKey()
```

The python tesseract can be found at

```
https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/
```

I found the conversion between the numpy array and iplimage here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528009/opencv-converting-from-numpy-to-iplimage-in-python
```

The cropping gives me 'here is' as text. It may not be exactly what you want.

Tesseract was searching for the trained language data in the tessdata folder in the same folder as the script. I just created a symlink to the /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata folder. You may wanna set the environment variable etc.

May be you should add a couple of more images. There is also the possibility to 
ocr the whole text, take the last line, since you are interested in the last line only, and see which word is in the middle.

I think you can use the code above to achieve both. The cropped area will give you a partial or full text of the word in the middle of the last line, which can then be used to select the full word from the text of the last line obtained using tesseract on the whole image.

Comment: hi binom, thanks. yes I am only interested in the exact one word in the middle area of the last line.  I don't know how many lines will be in the picture, it's random. I think the letter block at that position should be found by opencv, then processed by tesseract.

Comment: hi binom, thanks for your solution. This method is not what I want. As I have said, I don't know how many lines in the picture, and I don't know the the space between lines (it maybe not uniform), and what I know is: my word is located in the bottom line, and the vertical centerline penetrates it. The situation is more complicated. But thank you for your try.